# How to generate import section in wasm?

Tags: webassembly

When we compile an c source file into wasm, there will be lots of `import "env" xxxx` sections. For example, this is my c source file,

```
char message[] = "hello wasm!";
char* getMessageRef() {
      return message;
}
int getMessageLength() {
    return sizeof(message);
}

const int SIZE = 10;
int data[SIZE];

void add(int value) {
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        data[i] = data[i] + value;
    }
}

int* getData() {
    return &data[0];
}
```

After compiling,  related wat file will be

```
(module
  (type (;0;) (func (param i32 i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (type (;1;) (func (param i32) (result i32)))
  (type (;2;) (func (result i32)))
  (type (;3;) (func (param i32)))
  (type (;4;) (func (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (type (;5;) (func (param i32 i32)))
  (type (;6;) (func))
  (type (;7;) (func (param i32 i32 i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "memory" (memory (;0;) 256 256))
  (import "env" "table" (table (;0;) 10 10 anyfunc))
  (import "env" "memoryBase" (global (;0;) i32))
  (import "env" "tableBase" (global (;1;) i32))
  (import "env" "DYNAMICTOP_PTR" (global (;2;) i32))
  (import "env" "tempDoublePtr" (global (;3;) i32))
  (import "env" "ABORT" (global (;4;) i32))
  (import "env" "STACKTOP" (global (;5;) i32))
  (import "env" "STACK_MAX" (global (;6;) i32))
  (import "global" "NaN" (global (;7;) f64))
  (import "global" "Infinity" (global (;8;) f64))
  (import "env" "enlargeMemory" (func (;0;) (type 2)))
  (import "env" "getTotalMemory" (func (;1;) (type 2)))
  (import "env" "abortOnCannotGrowMemory" (func (;2;) (type 2)))
  (import "env" "abortStackOverflow" (func (;3;) (type 3)))
  (import "env" "nullFunc_ii" (func (;4;) (type 3)))
  (import "env" "nullFunc_iiii" (func (;5;) (type 3)))
  (import "env" "___lock" (func (;6;) (type 3)))
  (import "env" "___setErrNo" (func (;7;) (type 3)))
  (import "env" "___syscall140" (func (;8;) (type 4)))
  (import "env" "___syscall146" (func (;9;) (type 4)))
  (import "env" "___syscall54" (func (;10;) (type 4)))
  (import "env" "___syscall6" (func (;11;) (type 4)))
  (import "env" "___unlock" (func (;12;) (type 3)))
  (import "env" "_emscripten_memcpy_big" (func (;13;) (type 0)))
  (func (;14;) (type 1) (param i32) (result i32)
...  omit plenty of lines
```

So how should I export those section automatically when I instantiate wasm instance?

Answer (score 0):

When compiling C / C++ files with Emscripten it adds a lightweight runtime into the generated wasm output, this is why you see these various imports.

In order to execute, you need to set up a suitable JavaScript environment to host the wasm module. Emscripten can generate this for you:

```
./emcc tests/hello_world.c -o hello.html
```

The above will generate a `hello.html` file with associated JavaScript code that will allow you to execute your module.

For simple applications you can probably get away with creating the require environment yourself. Here's an example:

```
  const imports = {
    env: {
      memoryBase: 0,
      tableBase: 0,
      memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({
        initial: 512
      }),
      table: new WebAssembly.Table({
        initial: 0,
        element: 'anyfunc'
      })
    }
  };

  const instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(module, imports);
```

This is from an [example I wrote](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/wasm-mandelbrot/blob/master/emscripten/mandelbrot.js) that creates a Mandelbrot using C / Emscripten

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I just donot want to fill the `imports` manually.  Do you have ideas to do this more automatically?

Comment: When you use the option to generate the html file `./emcc tests/hello_world.c -o hello.html` the required JS host is created too.

Comment: I see.  Thanks.  I also have another scenario, I want to run the wasm by non-web interpreters, like WAVM or go-interpreter/wagon. Do you have any other idea?